# How to hide js socket connection?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, websocket, ratchet

I've recently build an socket with Ratchet (http://socketo.me/) in Symfony ( PHP framework ) with JS/jQuery. The problem im facing is that the socket IP+PORT are just visible in the js file, so everyone can connect with it using the console or something.

I'm executing several things with the socket, that impacts everyone's view that's connected with it.

Now I'm just able to open a new connection through the console using:

`var socket = new socket('http://www.IP:PORT');`

Then I'm able to use the send command to execute things that only the server should have access to. Like this:

`socket.send(JSON.stringify({info: 'information', action: 'runAction'}));`

Is there anyone that can explain me how to keep these send calls privately so not everyone can just have access to these actions and call them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to have these things stored in your php code and make an api say /getSocketDeatils
Now make an authenticated REST call to your api and make the socket when your app starts. 
This is just one way there can be multiple other